# How can I select datas with only the common dates in r?

Tags: r, select

I have a list with two cities and cities have data frames with 5 columns. Here is an example:

```
        date        nh1_min  nh2_min  nh3_min    cbh

2020-10-28 01:00:00   1      99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 02:00:00   1      99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 03:00:00   1      99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 04:00:00   1      99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 05:00:00   1      99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 06:00:00   1      99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 07:00:00   1      99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 08:00:00   1      99999     99999      6
2020-11-02 04:00:00   1      99999     99999      6

    
        date        nh1_min  nh2_min  nh3_min    cbh

2020-10-25 07:00:00  1       99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 00:00:00  1       99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 01:00:00  1       99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 02:00:00  1       99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 03:00:00  1       99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 06:00:00  1       99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 07:00:00  1       99999     99999      6
2020-10-28 08:00:00  1       99999     99999      6
2020-11-02 06:00:00  1       99999     99999      6
```

I have to select that datas when the date is the same. Here for example 2020-10-28 02:00:00, 2020-10-28 03:00:00 etc.
So in the end I will get two shorter data frame with only the common dates.
How can I select datas in this way? I tried so complicated if and for formulas and did not work.
(In my real project I have 10 cities and much more dates it's just a shorter form)

Example list:
`list(structure(list(ido = structure(c(1591840800, 1591858800,  1592449200, 1592452800, 1592456400, 1592463600, 1595120400, 1602529200,  1602835200, 1602993600, 1603602000, 1603609200, 1603843200, 1603846800,  1603850400, 1603854000, 1603864800, 1603868400, 1603872000, 1604296800,  1604332800, 1604358000, 1604383200, 1604430000, 1604703600, 1605290400,  1605297600, 1605301200, 1605502800, 1605510000, 1605819600, 1605823200,  1605826800, 1605830400, 1605834000, 1605837600, 1605841200, 1605844800,  1605852000, 1605859200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"),  nh1_min = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), nh2_min = c(6766, 662, 4572, 3720, 3635,  3737, 2915, 1144, 654, 99999, 778, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999,  99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 540, 99999, 99999, 629,  1225, 971, 947, 508, 2154, 2128, 1059, 99999, 99999, 483,  390, 999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 1308), nh3_min = c(99999,  99999, 99999, 4200, 99999, 99999, 99999, 2332, 99999, 99999,  1105, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999,  99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 6371, 99999, 99999, 99999, 667,  99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999,  99999, 99999, 2804), cbh = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)), row.names = c(643L, 648L,  770L, 771L, 772L, 774L, 844L, 1011L, 1099L, 1145L, 1321L, 1323L,  1391L, 1392L, 1393L, 1394L, 1397L, 1398L, 1399L, 1510L, 1521L,  1528L, 1535L, 1549L, 1628L, 1798L, 1800L, 1801L, 1859L, 1861L,  1951L, 1952L, 1953L, 1954L, 1955L, 1956L, 1957L, 1958L, 1960L,  1962L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(ido = structure(c(1581706800,  1581717600, 1581742800, 1581746400, 1603846800, 1603850400, 1603854000,  1603857600, 1603861200, 1603864800, 1603868400, 1603872000, 1604289600,  1604696400, 1604700000, 1604703600, 1605232800, 1605301200, 1605308400,  1605333600, 1605506400, 1605510000, 1605826800, 1605830400, 1605834000,  1605841200, 1605844800, 1607389200, 1607392800, 1607396400, 1607896800,  1607900400, 1607904000, 1608156000, 1608163200), class = c("POSIXct",  "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), nh1_min = c(1, 1, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), nh2_min = c(1576, 99999, 1641, 1615, 99999,  99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999,  99999, 99999, 508, 321, 163, 99999, 99999, 1508, 99999, 99999,  99999, 420, 1084, 99999, 1070, 324, 253, 99999, 99999, 449, 473 ), nh3_min = c(99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999,  99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999,  99999, 871, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999,  99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 638, 99999, 99999, 99999,  99999), cbh = c(6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,  6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)), row.names = c(215L,  218L, 225L, 226L, 1392L, 1393L, 1394L, 1395L, 1396L, 1397L, 1398L,  1399L, 1508L, 1626L, 1627L, 1628L, 1781L, 1801L, 1803L, 1810L,  1860L, 1861L, 1953L, 1954L, 1955L, 1957L, 1958L, 2155L, 2156L,  2157L, 2302L, 2303L, 2304L, 2377L, 2379L), class = "data.frame"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two dataframes from the list, create a date column, find the common dates and subset two dataframes to keep only the rows with common dates.

```
one <- data[[1]]
two <- data[[2]]
one <- transform(one, date = as.Date(ido))
two <- transform(two, date = as.Date(ido))
common_dates <- as.Date(intersect(one$date, two$date), origin = '1970-01-01')
one <- subset(one, date %in% common_dates)
two <- subset(two, date %in% common_dates)
```

---

For multiple dataframe we can keep the data in list itself.

```
common_dates <- as.Date(Reduce(intersect, lapply(data, function(x) 
                        as.Date(x$ido))), origin = '1970-01-01')

data <- lapply(data, function(x) subset(x, as.Date(ido) %in% common_dates))
```

Comment: It will be the good answear. But for me necessary that the common_dates contains the hours too. I search the common date with common hours. I was not perfectly accurate sorry.

Comment: If I use as.Posixct then works, thank you!

Comment: OH, one more question! My real project I have 10 data frames like this. How can I search tha common date and time that way? intersect can not work with more datas only with two but I have to work with ten data frames at the same time!

Comment: I have updated the answer for it to work for multiple dataframe at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

#df is your example data, which is a list 
df1 <- do.call(rbind, df)
df1 <- df1 %>% as_tibble(rownames = "id")

df2 <- df1 %>% filter(ido %in% ymd_hms("2020-10-18 03:00:00", "2020-10-28 02:00:00"))
df2

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  id    ido                 nh1_min nh2_min nh3_min   cbh
  <chr> <dttm>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 1393  2020-10-28 02:00:00       1   99999   99999     6
2 13931 2020-10-28 02:00:00       1   99999   99999     6
```